# status=401, error=Unauthorized, message=Full authentication is required to access this resource in Spring Framework when trying to receive a token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

After entering credentials some users receive "status=401, error=Unauthorized, message=Full authentication is required to access this resource, path=/backend/oauth/token" error. We can not really reproduce the error, for most of our clients, everything works fine.

I am using Spring Framework 1.5.6 for our back-end. The requests are done from our front-end on Angular 7.

We added

```
.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token");
```

also tried to reorder CORS filters. Nothing helped.

```
019-10-01 23:01:06.120 DEBUG 758 --- [gine[Catalina]]] o.a.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext    : Checking JSPs for unload in context [/backend], JSP count: [0] queue length: [-1]2019-10-01 23:24:23.196 DEBUG 758 --- [io-8080-exec-17] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request OPTIONS /backend/oauth/token
2019-10-01 23:24:23.197 DEBUG 758 --- [io-8080-exec-17] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    :  Not subject to any constraint
2019-10-01 23:24:23.197 DEBUG 758 --- [io-8080-exec-17] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper   :   Returning non-STM instance
2019-10-01 23:24:25.368 DEBUG 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request POST /backend/oauth/token
2019-10-01 23:24:25.368 DEBUG 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    :  Not subject to any constraint
2019-10-01 23:24:25.368 DEBUG 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper   :   Returning non-STM instance
2019-10-01 23:24:25.373 DEBUG 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper   :   Returning non-STM instance
2019-10-01 23:24:25.374 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Bound request context to thread: FirewalledRequest[ org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper@22972b19]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.374 DEBUG 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/backend/error]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.374 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@309baf41] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-10-01 23:24:25.374 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : No handler mapping found for [/error]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.374 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [springfox.documentation.spring.web.PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping@7fb76a70] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-10-01 23:24:25.374 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@3294e0d8] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-10-01 23:24:25.374 DEBUG 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2019-10-01 23:24:25.494 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Found 2 matching mapping(s) for [/error] : [{[/error]}, {[/error],produces=[text/html]}]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.494 DEBUG 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.494 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@7da395b2]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.494 DEBUG 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.s.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor        : Skip CORS processing: response already contains "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header
2019-10-01 23:24:25.495 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver@21e87b12] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.495 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver@315e17b2] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.495 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver@538cca60] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.495 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.PathVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver@372e5023] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.495 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MatrixVariableMethodArgumentResolver@16565af5] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.495 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MatrixVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver@27f4c866] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.495 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor@351af9f] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.495 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor@75b3d783] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.495 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver@66241e38] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.495 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver@67925d62] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.495 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestHeaderMapMethodArgumentResolver@69b12b58] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.495 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletCookieValueMethodArgumentResolver@255e622] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.495 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExpressionValueMethodArgumentResolver@5141d7a3] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.495 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SessionAttributeMethodArgumentResolver@7c085f5f] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.495 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestAttributeMethodArgumentResolver@37560265] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.495 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver@482120ab] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.495 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Invoking 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error' with arguments [FirewalledRequest[ org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper@22972b19]]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.496 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Method [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error] returned [<401 Unauthorized,{timestamp=Tue Oct 01 23:24:25 UTC 2019, status=401, error=Unauthorized, message=Full authentication is required to access this resource, path=/backend/oauth/token},{}>]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.497 DEBUG 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Written [{timestamp=Tue Oct 01 23:24:25 UTC 2019, status=401, error=Unauthorized, message=Full authentication is required to access this resource, path=/backend/oauth/token}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@7b51e806]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.498 DEBUG 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2019-10-01 23:24:25.498 TRACE 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Cleared thread-bound request context: FirewalledRequest[ org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper@22972b19]
2019-10-01 23:24:25.498 DEBUG 758 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```